# Gradle build running demorando uma eternidade

Tags: android-studio, gradle

O Android Studio não está mais copilando o projeto. Já desinstalei e instalei novamente mas não resolve, fica só nessa de "Gradle build running" e nunca finaliza.

```
22:21:33 Gradle sync started
22:23:58 Gradle sync completed
22:24:00 Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
```

Também ja fui em "File > Settings Build,Execution,Deployment> Build Tools>" Gradle e habilitei o opção "Offline work" e também não deu nada.

O que faço?

Comment: olá @Léo, eu tive esse problema aqui, resolvi ele criando um projeto novo com o mesmo nome e copiando os arquivos e pastas pertinentes do antigo para o novo, por pertinentes digo, os arquivos da pasta "src/main/seudominio/seuprojeto/*.java" e a pasta "res". avisa se funcionou

Comment: Será que vai da algum problema para meus usuários atualizar? meu app está na Play store.

Comment: voce precisa fazer tudo igual, o nome do projeto, o nome do dominio, o nome do pacote, em fim, faz um zerado como se tivesse fazendo pela primeira vez, e tambem lembre-se de por a versão correta e copia a tua signed key, outra coisa importante, melhor se voce copiar do seu gerenciador de arquivos e colar pelo proprio studio, clicando nos locais onde voce quer colar

Comment: infelizmente, a forma como eu consegui resolver isso foi assim, pois tentei de tudo, tentei resetar o cache, apaqguei o sdk, apaguei a pasta ".studio" e nem com uma instalação nova do android studio funcionou, dai fiz isso e resolveu.

Comment: Outra coisa, não lembro bem o nome de domínio do meu App, sabe onde acho em algum  arquivo? só lembro do pacote

Comment: o nome do dominio é algo como: com.seudominio.seupacote, abre a pasta "app/main/seudominio/seupacote" ai está o nome completo que voce precisa usar, geralmente, o nome do pacote no manifest é o nome do dominio e do pacote composto

Comment: Ok, vou tentar aqui e ti aviso! Obrigado!

Comment: Conseguir resolver aqui e vou postar uma resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguir resolver esse problema, no Windows 10.
A eternidade mostra um erro no logs em **Gradle console**.
Então, vá em **Meu Computador** > **Propriedades** > **Mostrar configurações avançadas** > **Variável de ambiente**.

Clique no botão **Novo** e coloque os detalhes abaixo:

```
Nome da Variável: SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT
Valor: 50
```

> Vale lembrar que o Java está sendo bloqueado pelo o firewall, sendo do Windows ou de terceiro. No meu caso, eu uso o anti-vírus Kaspersky Lab, então desativei e quando fui recompilar, o firewall do Windows avisou que o Java queria permissão para acessar internet.

A solução é permitir, então permiti em ambos firewall e a gradle compilou com sucesso em uns 7 minutos!

Comment: vixe, fica entaum os meus comentários para quem usa outros SO's, por enquanto serve como um atalho para nós que abolimos o windows, pois eu uso linux já de há muito e se alguém aqui tiver uma solução parecida com a do amigo @Leo ae, mas para para os outros sistemas operacionais, seria muito bem vinda

Comment: Eu ia fazer do jeito que você explicou, como vi que era muito trabalhoso, vi um atalho do **Gradle console** e teve as mensagens de erro, foi assim que conseguir resolver. Tenta ver a mensagem de erro e faz uma pergunta, quê alguém que usa Linux deve ti ajudar! Muito obrigado pelo os seus comentários!

Comment: De fato @Léo, eu tbn me cansei de camelar com isso e fui atras da solução para linux, o que me resolveu isso, foi instalar as bibliotecas para 32 bits na minha maquina que é 64 bits, dai, o caso é instalar essas libs: `sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686`, aqui eu uso SCL 7 (RHEL), para uma distro baseado no debian, tem de fazer: `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386`. dai funcionou redondinho.